# PHP and HTML programming, Login page

Tags: php, html, database

no matter the input the code goes to loginhandler.php
I think its because of the while loop any ideas?

```
 if($okay == TRUE){
     $dbc = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('coursework_network', $dbc);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE username = '" . $username . "' AND     password='"     .$password . "'";
    if ($result = mysql_query($query, $dbc)) {// Run the query.
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $okay = TRUE;
        }
    } else {
        $okay = FALSE;
    }
}
if ($okay) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: loginhandler.php');
    exit();
} else {
    $onError = "Invalid username and/or password";
}
```

Comment: Where is `$okay` being set? Obviously it is set before this code is run as it is checked in your first if statement. Any value that does not equal false will cause what you see to happen.

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: **Do not store passswords in plain text**.

Comment: Security is **hard**.  Do not reinvent the wheel.  You should use an existing, proven authentication system.

Answer (score 0):

Pay close attention the comments in your question, but it looks like you never set `$okay` to false in the case where the query returns 0 records.

`mysql_num_rows` is going to be true if the query is valid and you have permissions, so you need to account for this either inside that control block where you check for a valid record, or by immediately setting  `$okay` to false immediately after the first `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic and variable use is very confused here.

In the situation where `$okay` is true at the top of your script, it will never be set to false, because as long as  your `mysql_query` doesn't error, your `$okay = FALSE` code will never execute.

There's a whole bunch wrong with your code that needs addressing, and I'd suggest you take a look at a couple of things in particular:

- mysql_query is deprecated, and not a good function to be using. Use PDO or mysqli_* functions instead.
- Your code is vulnerable to sql injection. Using prepared statements should resolve this (by using PDO), failing that, sanitize your inputs!
- To determine if a query has returned any results, you can use the mysql_num_rows function, which takes a result as a parameter.

This last point should help resolve your issue in this case. If you instead do:

```
if($okay == TRUE){
    $dbc = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('coursework_network', $dbc);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE username = '" . $username . "' AND password='"     .$password . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $dbc))

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $okay = true;
    } else {
        $okay = false;
    }
}
if ($okay) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: loginhandler.php');
    exit();
} else {
    $onError = "Invalid username and/or password";
}
```

you should have more success.

Seriously, though, this code needs some serious refactoring. Look into the points I posted above, and take some time to understand the issues there. They are important!